# We don't say "hear out" so what do we say?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Please help me determine what to say when we can't quite "pick out" the words that someone is saying.

For example, say you're a student of a given language. You hear a native speaker speaking their native language. Maybe they're speaking faster than you can keep up with, or you're unfamiliar with their accent or pronunciation, or you simply don't know the words they're saying.

Do you say, *"They're saying words that you can't identify / can't pick out / can't "hear" / don't understand."*? Or, would you not use any of these?

It seems to me that "can't pick out" is best for this situation, but I'm just not certain. I'd like others' opinions.

In Thai language, it's "can't hear it out" but this of course isn't right for English. I hear students say various other things, none of which ever feel right to me.

I hope my question is understandable. Thanks very much.

Comment: You don't need a preposition with ***hear*** when you're using the verb with its normal ***default*** sense - only if you need to convey some different "nuance", as in ***Hear me out*** (don't just listen to my *initial* words; keep listening until I've finished making my point). Similar to *See the job **through**, See an intruder **off**, See your visitor **out***, where the preposition significantly affects the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

If we cannot understand what someone is saying, because he or she (e.g.) is talking too fast, or too quietly, or has a thick accent, or there are loud noises nearby, or a phone connection is bad, etc, we can say that we can't 'make out' what they are saying.

> make out
>
> PHRASAL VERB
>
> Manage with some difficulty to see or hear someone or something.

[Make out (Oxford Dictionary)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/make_out)

Comment: YESSSSSS! THAT'S it :) Cool :) Thanks a ton :)